# Можно ли с Chronometr в Android получить текущее время для передачи его в другое активити?

Tags: java, android

Я использую класс Chronometr чтоб выводить пользователю время которое он тратит на выполнение задания и когда он заканчивает выполнение мне нужно взять данные с Chronometr и передать в активити с результатами. Я посмотрел документацию,но не нашел там функцию `getTime()` или что то вроде этого. Как я могу передать время в следующее активити?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы посмотрите на источник класса хронометр, вы увидите, что он не сохраняет прошедшее время в поле, а вычисляет его каждый раз когда запрашиваете.

Вот пример:

```
public class ChronoExample extends Activity {
Chronometer mChronometer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

mChronometer = new Chronometer(this);
layout.addView(mChronometer);

Button startButton = new Button(this);
startButton.setText("Start");
startButton.setOnClickListener(mStartListener);
layout.addView(startButton);

Button stopButton = new Button(this);
stopButton.setText("Stop");
stopButton.setOnClickListener(mStopListener);
layout.addView(stopButton);

Button resetButton = new Button(this);
resetButton.setText("Reset");
resetButton.setOnClickListener(mResetListener);
layout.addView(resetButton);        

setContentView(layout);
}

private void showElapsedTime() {
long elapsedMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() -   mChronometer.getBase();            
Toast.makeText(ChronoExample.this, "Elapsed milliseconds: " + elapsedMillis, 
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

View.OnClickListener mStartListener = new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
    mChronometer.start();
    showElapsedTime();
}
};

View.OnClickListener mStopListener = new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
    mChronometer.stop();
    showElapsedTime();
}
};

View.OnClickListener mResetListener = new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
    mChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
    showElapsedTime();
}
};
}
```

Под себя переделаете, потом отправите на второе Активити!

Answer (score 0):

Вот еще метод, без наследования хронометра. Просто измените метод mStartListener(1-ответ), рассчитать миллисекунды, и использовать setBase (), чтобы скорректировать базовое время:

```
  View.OnClickListener mStartListener = new OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {

  int stoppedMilliseconds = 0;

  String chronoText = mChronometer.getText().toString();
  String array[] = chronoText.split(":");
  if (array.length == 2) {
    stoppedMilliseconds = Integer.parseInt(array[0]) * 60 * 1000
        + Integer.parseInt(array[1]) * 1000;
  } else if (array.length == 3) {
    stoppedMilliseconds = Integer.parseInt(array[0]) * 60 * 60 * 1000 
        + Integer.parseInt(array[1]) * 60 * 1000
        + Integer.parseInt(array[2]) * 1000;
  }

  mChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() -  stoppedMilliseconds);
  mChronometer.start();
}
};
```